# How to visualize a high dimensional data set that I fitted using MiniBatchKmeans

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, data-visualization, k-means

Context: So I have a data set of 32k images that are each 200x200 and are black and white. I turned the 200x200 photo into a single dimension of 40k in row major order. I basically have a 32k x 40k numpy matrix with the first value being the image index and the second value being 1 or 0 for the pixel index for that particular image. I ran MiniBatkKmeans on it as such:

```
with open('np_array.pickle', 'rb') as handle:
    np_list = pickle.load(handle)

# used a batch system for k mean so my machine doesn't run out of memory
mbk = MiniBatchKMeans(init='k-means++', n_clusters=5,
                      batch_size=200,
                      max_no_improvement=10, verbose=0)
mbk.fit(np_list)
```

Now I want to know what's the best way to 'see' this data set and all the clusters that were formed if and each photos relations to each other if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can perform a dimensionality reduction like Multidimensional Scaling (MDS) on your high dimensional feature vectors. So you would reduce the 32k feature vectors from 40k to 1, 2 or 3 dimensions.

I can't tell you if MDS is the best method to perform dimensionality reduction with your data. Have a look at [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/dimensionality-reduction-toolbox-in-python-9a18995927cd) blog post, there are a lot of methods described.

In the end you'll have 32k 1-,2- or 3-d datapoints which can be visualized quite easily. Colorcode your data points according to their cluster and if you are lucky, they are separated in the projection, too.

Answer (score 0):

[T-SNE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T-distributed_stochastic_neighbor_embedding) might be helpful for visualising the output of clustering algorithms. It shows similar points close to each other, and dissimilar ones apart in the low dimensional space. [This](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/introduction-t-sne) article shows how it can be done in python. Depending on the usecase you might want to approach PCA or other algorithms mentioned in the link mentioned in the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

Don't expect k-means to work well on 40000 dimensions of pixel values. You need to extract better features.
Most likely almost all the data will be in one cluster anyway.

Anyway, forget scatterplots here.

But each center is also 200x200 pixels. So you can visualize the "average" picture of each cluster easily. Then also visualize some of the nearest and farthest samples in the cluster.

And then you'll see that it didn't produce useful clusters.